# java IF NOT statement

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Guess a number betwwen 1 and 1000");

        Random rand = new Random(); 
        int secretNumber = rand.nextInt (1000);


        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guess;

        do {
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (guess == secretNumber)
            System.out.println("You WON!!! Congratulations!");
        else if (guess < secretNumber)
             System.out.println("Nope, to low");
        else if (guess > secretNumber)
            System.out.println("Sorry, to high");


        } while (guess != secretNumber);


    }
}
```

how can i add to this code a statement, that IF NOT NUMERIC INPUT System.out.println("invalid input, please use type numbers only!")

Comment: You need to look at the doc for Scanner and see how it reports a non-numeric input for `nextInt`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `Scanner`'s `hasNextInt()` method to determine if the input is numeric before calling `nextInt`:

```
do {
    while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Please enter only numbers.");
        keyboard.next(); // Skip the wrong token
    }
    // Now that the input is valid, read the value:
    guess = keyboard.nextInt();
    // Put the rest of your logic here
    ...
} while (guess != secretNumber);
```

Answer (score 3):

Scanner.nextInt() throws 
`InputMismatchException` if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range

So you should wrap your code around a try-catch with this in mind

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the following wrapped around guess = keyboard.nextInt():

```
 try  
 {  
     guess = keyboard.nextInt()
     Integer.parseInt(guess);  

     <your if statements>

  } catch(Exception ex)  
  {  
    System.out.println("Your comment");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a try catch block inside your loop.

```
  do {
  try{
    guess = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (guess == secretNumber)
        System.out.println("You WON!!! Congratulations!");
    else if (guess < secretNumber)
         System.out.println("Nope, to low");
    else if (guess > secretNumber)
        System.out.println("Sorry, to high");
    }
catch(InputMismatchException e){
System.out.prinln("Not a number");
}


    } while (guess != secretNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

While using a scanner you will never figure out if it is an integer that has been entered or not. It will just wait until the "nextInt" is entered. What you can do is use the

[Integer.parseInt() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29). It will throw a NumberFormatException if the input string is not an integer.

Make guess a string and use. guess = keyboard.next();

Then use Integer.parseInt(guess) in a try-catch to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Guess a number betwwen 1 and 1000");

    Random rand = new Random(); 
    int secretNumber = rand.nextInt (1000);


    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int guess;

    do {
    if (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("invalid input, please use type numbers only!");
        return;
    }
    guess = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (guess == secretNumber)
        System.out.println("You WON!!! Congratulations!");
    else if (guess < secretNumber)
         System.out.println("Nope, to low");
    else if (guess > secretNumber)
        System.out.println("Sorry, to high");


    } while (guess != secretNumber);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {
    public static boolean isInteger( String input )  
    {  
       try  
       {  
          Integer.parseInt( input );  
          return true;  
       }  
       catch( Exception e)  
       {  
          return false;  
       }  
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Guess a number betwwen 1 and 1000");

        Random rand = new Random(); 
        int secretNumber = rand.nextInt (1000);

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guess=-1;

        do {
        String g = keyboard.next();
        if(isInteger(g)){
            guess = Integer.parseInt(g);
            if (guess == secretNumber)
                System.out.println("You WON!!! Congratulations!");
            else if (guess < secretNumber)
                System.out.println("Nope, to low");
            else if (guess > secretNumber)
                System.out.println("Sorry, to high");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("NaN");
        }

        } while (guess != secretNumber);


    }
}
```